# Add Printer not working

Tags: 14.04, printing

When I bring up printers and then click add printer the program just closes, when running `sudo system-config-printer` in the command terminal I get this error message.

```
Error in `/usr/bin/python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000013437f0
```

Don't know what it means or how to fix it, can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the 'Install VMware Tools', this inserts two new links in `/usr/lib/cups/backend/` which renders all printing useless -- no matter what you try!

The solution, move to the directory in question:

```
cd /usr/lib/cups/backend/
```

List the files there. The `-lFat` is just to see everything 'nicely' :-)

```
ls -lFat
```

If you see something like this, they are the problem:

```
tpvmgp -> /usr/lib/vmware-tools/bin/vmware-tpvmlp
tpvmlp -> /usr/lib/vmware-tools/bin/vmware-tpvmlp
```

The solution, just remove them:

```
sudo rm tpvmgp
sudo rm tpvmlp
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-818720.html